# ReactDOM.render: Unable to find node on an unmounted component after React upgrade from 16.4.2 to 16.5.2

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, material-ui

I have updated ReactJS project to the latest version with `npm update` running from Visual Studio 2017 with following results:

```
+ @material-ui/icons@2.0.3
+ react-dom@16.5.2
+ @material-ui/core@1.5.1
+ react@16.5.2
+ @aspnet/signalr@1.0.4
added 4 packages from 3 contributors, removed 10 packages, updated 20 packages and audited 185 packages in 23.309s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

When I run `npm outdated` I still get:

```
Package             Current  Wanted  Latest  Location
@material-ui/core     1.5.1   1.5.1   3.2.0  Dixie
@material-ui/icons    2.0.3   2.0.3   3.0.1  Dixie
```

Now when I run the project, that worked before update, I get

> ReactDOM.render: Unable to find node on an unmounted component.

Here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "Dixie",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.5",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.24.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "^1.1.4",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "rimraf ./build && react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

How to fix this error after React update to 16.5.2?

---

I did

```
npm install  @material-ui/icons@3.0.1
npm install  @material-ui/core@3.2.0
npm cache clean --force
```

now `npm outdated` shows nothing but the error remains.

Tried also (without any gain):

```
npm uninstall --save react-dom
npm uninstall --save react
npm install react-dom
npm install react
```

The only thing that "works" is downgrade

```
npm install react-dom@16.4.2
npm install react@16.4.2
```

But it means I am unable to upgrade. Tried also another computer with the same project and the same error came out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue. Finally upgrade React and React-dom to 16.6.0 helped.

Comment: Indeed. Could you provide some background or explanation?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to uninstall/remove the broken packages and install updated one.

You can downgrade React to 16.4.2. this way:

```
npm uninstall --save react-dom
npm uninstall --save react
npm install react-dom@16.4.2
npm install react@16.4.2
```

Comment: I do not have any broken packages. `npm-check` tells me `Your modules look amazing. Keep up the great work.`

Comment: Seems good to me. Have you tried completely removing and installing again?

Comment: I struggled with this error message for a couple of days, and it never dawned on me to update `react-dom` along with `react`.  Seeing this Q&A triggered the lightbulb for me.  Thanks!

Comment: @robabby you mean you fixed the error using version 16.5.2? I am still downgraded on 16.4.2...

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal Yeah for my use case I have a UI Component Library we are building as a dependency of a larger project. I updated `react` and `react-dom` to 16.5.2 in both solutions and the error was resolved for me.

Comment: @robabby Hm, for me running those updates to 16.5.2 causes still the mentioned error.

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal bummer, man.  Wish I could be more helpful.  This error isn't very descriptive.

Comment: are you using `enzyme-adapter-react-16`? Try to update it to latest version. Luck may work.